# Haskell: Thread and IO type

Tags: haskell

I am studying the Haskell to the thread part. I try to create 2 threads to do the different calculation. This is a really simple function just for practice. The code like this:

```
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO)

task4 a b = do
    forkIO $ a^b
    forkIO $ b^a


    if (a^b) > (b^a) then putStrLn ([a] ++ "^"++[b] ++ "=" ++ [a^b] ++ "is bigger!")
                    else putStrLn ([b] ++ "^"++[a] ++ "=" ++ [b^a] ++ "is bigger!")
```

I don't know how to dual with the type inside the do block. And am I right to create threads like this?

Comment: Did you have a look at http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html yet?

Comment: Actually, I am just reading it now

Comment: Note that you probably don't want concurrency with threads, but parallel programming. That's about halfway into the chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since some time has passed, here's how you would do it with threads:

```
-- helper function for all other methods
message a b = (show a) ++ " ? " ++ (show b) ++ " " ++ (show . compare a $ b)

threads a b = do
  abVar <- newEmptyMVar
  baVar <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO $ putMVar abVar (a^b)
  forkIO $ putMVar baVar (b^a)
  ab <- takeMVar abVar
  ba <- takeMVar baVar
  putStrLn $ message ab ba
```

That's a mouthful. Even worse, it's not pure anymore. After all, your program is basically nothing more than

```
simple a b = message (a^b) (b^a)

-- IO version
simpleIO :: Integer -> Integer -> IO ()
simpleIO a b = putStrLn $ simple a b
```

Or at least it should behave the same. If you want to do this in parallel, there's no need for `IO`, using [`par` and `pseq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.0.4/docs/Control-Parallel.html#v%3apar):

```
parAB a b = force ab `par` force ba `pseq` message ab ba
  where ab = a^b
        ba = b^a

-- IO version    
parABIO a b = putStrLn $ parAB a b
```

But in the end, using parallel or concurrent techniques on such simple tasks as `a^b` won't gain you anything:

> `par` is generally used when the value of `a` is likely to be required later, but not immediately. Also it is a good idea to ensure that `a` is not a trivial computation, otherwise the cost of spawning it in parallel overshadows the benefits obtained by running it in parallel.

This can be checked by using Criterion:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Parallel
import Control.DeepSeq
import Criterion.Main

message a b = (show a) ++ " ? " ++ (show b) ++ " " ++ (show . compare a $ b)

simple, parAB :: Integer -> Integer -> String
simpleIO, parABIO, threads :: Integer -> Integer -> IO ()

simple a b = message (a^b) (b^a)

simpleIO a b = putStrLn $ simple a b

parAB a b = force ab `par` force ba `pseq` message ab ba
  where ab = a^b
        ba = b^a

parABIO a b = putStrLn $ parAB a b 

threads a b = do
  abVar <- newEmptyMVar
  baVar <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO $ putMVar abVar (a^b)
  forkIO $ putMVar baVar (b^a)
  ab <- takeMVar abVar
  ba <- takeMVar baVar
  putStrLn $ message ab ba

main = defaultMain [
  bgroup "simpleIO" 
    [ bench "1531235 123152123" $ whnf (simpleIO 1531235) 123152123
    , bench "2 121351356" $ whnf (simpleIO 2) 121351356
    , bench "12346 415" $ whnf (simpleIO 12346) 415
    ],
  bgroup "parABIO" 
    [ bench "1531235 123152123" $ whnf (parABIO 1531235) 123152123
    , bench "2 121351356" $ whnf (parABIO 2) 121351356
    , bench "12346 415" $ whnf (parABIO 12346) 415
    ],
  bgroup "threads" 
    [ bench "1531235 123152123" $ whnf (threads 1531235) 123152123
    , bench "2 121351356" $ whnf (threads 2) 121351356
    , bench "12346 415" $ whnf (threads 12346) 415
    ]
  ]
```

#### Further resources

- [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/index.html)
- [Chapter 24. Concurrent and multicore programming](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html) of Real World Haskell

Comment: Thanks a lot, and can you help me with another problem? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054298/haskell-io-type-in-the-do-block?noredirect=1#comment33441476_22054298)