# Haskell: how to operate the string type in a do block

Tags: haskell

I want to make a function that firstly divides a list l to two list m and n. Then create two thread to find out the longest palindrome in the two list. My code is :

```
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO)
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

main = do
    l <- getArgs
    forkIO $ putStrLn $ show $ longestPalindr $ mList l
    forkIO $ putStrLn $ show $ longestPalindr $ nList l

longestPalindr x =
    snd $ last $ sort $
        map (\l -> (length l, l)) $
            map head $ group $ sort $
                filter (\y -> y == reverse y) $
                    concatMap inits $ tails x

mList l = take (length l `div` 2) l

nList l = drop (length l `div` 2) l
```

Now I can compile it, but the result is a [ ]. When I just run the `longestPalindr` and `mList` , I get the right result. I thought the logic here is right. So what is the problem?

Comment: So what am I wrong here?@bheklilr

Comment: This compiles fine for me. I don't think `longestPalindr` does what you want it to do. Also, since there's no real IO involved, it may be more sensible to consider using `par` and `seq`, then let the runtime parallelise it for you, rather than using `forkIO`.

Comment: `longestPalindr` get the longest palindrome in a string. But anyway I am interested in how to use `par` to duel with it. Would you please show me how to do it?@bheklilr

Comment: Actually I got a [] of this code... What's wrong here?

Comment: To be clear, you want to accept a list of strings, and return the longest palindrome from any of the strings? Or rather do you just want to find the longest full argument that happens to be palindrome?

Comment: Yes, l is a string list. Firstly, I divides it to two string lists, m and n. @shelf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question title may need to be changed, as this is no longer about type errors.

The functionality of the program can be fixed by simply mapping `longestPalindr` across the two halves of the list. In your code, you are finding the longest palindrome across `[[Char]]`, so the result length is usually just 1.

I've given a simple example of `par` and `pseq`. This just suggests to the compiler that it may be smart to evaluate left and right independently. It doesn't guarantee parallel evaluation, but rather leaves it up to the compiler to decide.

Consult [Parallel Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parallel) on the wiki to understand sparks, compile with the `-threaded` flag, then run it with `+RTS -N2`. Add `-stderr` for profiling, and see if there is any benefit to sparking here. I would expect negative returns until you start to feed it longer lists.

For further reading on functional parallelism, take a look at [`Control.Parallel.Strategies`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.1.0.1/docs/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html). Manually wrangling threads in Haskell is only really needed in nondeterministic scenarios.

```
import Control.Parallel (par, pseq)
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Data.List
import Data.Ord
import Control.Function (on)

main = do
    l <- getArgs
    let left = map longestPalindr (mList l)
        right = map longestPalindr (nList l)
    left `par` right `pseq` print $ longest (left ++ right)

longestPalindr x = longest pals
    where pals = nub $ filter (\y -> y == reverse y) substrings
          substrings = concatMap inits $ tails x

longest = maximumBy (compare `on` length)

mList l = take (length l `div` 2) l

nList l = drop (length l `div` 2) l
```

Comment: Thanks, and I have tried just add map to my code. `forkIO $ putStrLn $ show $ map longestPalindr (mList l)`, I still got a []. Am I put the map wrong place?

Comment: I got erroneous answers until I replaced `snd $ last $ sort` with `maximum`.

Comment: But I don't want get the length, just want the longest string. So I need the `snd $ last $ sort` in my code. So how do duel with the [[Char]] problem?

Comment: try `maximumBy (compare \`on\` length)`

Answer (score 0):

For reference, please read the `Parallel`chapter from Simon Marlow's book.
http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch02.html#sec_par-eval-whnf

As others have stated, using `par` from the `Eval` monad seems to be the correct approach here.
Here is a simplified view of your problem. You can test it out by compiling with `+RTS -threaded -RTS`and then you can use [Thread Scope](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/ThreadScope) to profile your performance.

```
import           Control.Parallel.Strategies 
import           Data.List                   (maximumBy, subsequences)
import           Data.Ord

isPalindrome :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
isPalindrome xs = xs == reverse xs

-- * note while subsequences is correct, it is asymptotically
-- inefficient due to nested foldr calls

getLongestPalindrome :: Ord a => [a] -> Int
getLongestPalindrome = length . maximum' . filter isPalindrome . subsequences
  where maximum' :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]
        maximum' = maximumBy $ comparing length    

--- Do it in parallel, in a monad
-- rpar rpar seems to fit your case, according to Simon Marlow's book
-- http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch02.html#sec_par-eval-whnf
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let shorter = [2,3,4,5,4,3,2]
      longer  = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
      result = runEval $ do
                 a <- rpar $ getLongestPalindrome shorter
                 b <- rpar $ getLongestPalindrome longer
                 if a > b -- 'a > b' will always be false in this case
                 then return (a,"shorter")
                 else return (b,"longer")
  print result
-- This will print the length of the longest palindrome along w/ the list name
-- Don't forget to compile w/ -threaded and use ThreadScope to check
-- performance and evaluation
```

Comment: No problem ;) glad to help. Feel free to accept the question if it helped you. Stick w/ Haskell!